# Change text color of tabs

Tags: java, android, xml

i'm trying to make scrollable tabs. I got it all working but i don't know how to change the text color of the individual tabs, this is my code...
XML(MainActivity):

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ViewPager viewPager = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceStats) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceStats);
        setContentView(R.layout.homescreen);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));
    }
}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if(position == 0) {
            fragment = new FragmentDominik();
        } else if(position == 1) {
            fragment = new FragmentTobias();
        } else if(position == 2) {
            fragment = new FragmentTom();
        } else if(position == 3) {
            fragment = new FragmentNikolas();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String title = new String();
        if(position == 0) {
            return "Dominik";
        } else if(position == 1) {
            return "Tobias";
        } else if(position == 2) {
            return "Tom";
        } else if(position == 3) {
            return "Nikolas";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

so the default text color is black, but i want the text to be white and (i already got that)the background to be black, here's a picture:

[image: i want the pink bar to be black and the text in the pink bar to be white]

I'm kind of new to xml and java and I just used a tutorial online to make this scrollable tabs, so any help is appreciated :) thanks

Comment: Are you just looking for `android:textColor="#ffffff"`?

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest to add a style to your PagerTitleStrip:

```
<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        style="@style/your_style"
        />
```

And then in your styles.xml:

```
<style name="your_style">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```